# How to open db file in android studio for flutter project?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

This is the location of database

[image]

And I have this error when I open the db

`Error opening contents of device file "app_gmao.db": 'secure_mkdirs failed: Operation not permitted' error on device serial #emulator-5554 executing service 'sync-send('/data/local/tmp/device-explorer/.__temp_cp_test_file__.tmp')'`

Comment: try to open on real device.